# java.lang.IllegalStateException: Failed to load ApplicationContext error java spring-boot

Tags: java, spring, unit-testing, spring-mvc

Okay i went through a lot of answers but my problem is still unsolved.
I am  trying to test my controller -

```
@Controller
@Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
@RequestMapping(value = "/verify/email")
public class EmailController {

@Autowired
private ByEmail strategy;

@Autowired
private ApplicationConfig config;

@ResponseBody
@RequestMapping(method = RequestMethod.POST, produces = 
MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
public Request newRequest(@RequestBody VRequest request) throws 
IOException {
    log.info(request.toString());
    System.out.println(request.toString());
    request.setType(VType.EMAIL);
    Optional<Request> response = strategy.processRequest(request);
    return response.orElseThrow(BadRequestException::new);
}
```

And my test is -

```
@RunWith(SpringRunner.class)
@AutoConfigureMockMvc
@WebAppConfiguration
@SpringBootTest
public class TestEmailController {

@Mock
private ByEmail strategy;

@InjectMocks
@Autowired
private EmailController controller;

@Autowired
private MockMvc mockMvc;

@Test
public void contexLoads() throws Exception {
    assertThat(controller).isNotNull();
}
```

When I tried to run the test it is giving following error -

```
java.lang.IllegalStateException: Failed to load ApplicationContext

at org.springframework.test.context.cache.DefaultCacheAwareContextLoaderDelegate.loadContext(DefaultCacheAwareContextLoaderDelegate.java:124)
at org.springframework.test.context.support.DefaultTestContext.getApplicationContext(DefaultTestContext.java:83)
at org.springframework.test.context.web.ServletTestExecutionListener.setUpRequestContextIfNecessary(ServletTestExecutionListener.java:189)
at org.springframework.test.context.web.ServletTestExecutionListener.prepareTestInstance(ServletTestExecutionListener.java:131)
at org.springframework.test.context.TestContextManager.prepareTestInstance(TestContextManager.java:230)
at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.createTest(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:228)
at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner$1.runReflectiveCall(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:287)
at org.junit.internal.runners.model.ReflectiveCallable.run(ReflectiveCallable.java:12)
at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.methodBlock(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:289)
at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:247)
at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:94)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$3.run(ParentRunner.java:290)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$1.schedule(ParentRunner.java:71)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runChildren(ParentRunner.java:288)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.access$000(ParentRunner.java:58)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$2.evaluate(ParentRunner.java:268)
at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.statements.RunBeforeTestClassCallbacks.evaluate(RunBeforeTestClassCallbacks.java:61)
at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.statements.RunAfterTestClassCallbacks.evaluate(RunAfterTestClassCallbacks.java:70)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.run(ParentRunner.java:363)
at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.run(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:191)
at org.junit.runner.JUnitCore.run(JUnitCore.java:137)
at com.intellij.junit4.JUnit4IdeaTestRunner.startRunnerWithArgs(JUnit4IdeaTestRunner.java:68)
at com.intellij.rt.execution.junit.IdeaTestRunner$Repeater.startRunnerWithArgs(IdeaTestRunner.java:47)
at com.intellij.rt.execution.junit.JUnitStarter.prepareStreamsAndStart(JUnitStarter.java:242)
at com.intellij.rt.execution.junit.JUnitStarter.main(JUnitStarter.java:70)

Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'application': Unsatisfied dependency expressed through field 'configs'; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'applicationConfig': Could not bind properties to ApplicationConfig (prefix=company.services.verification, ignoreInvalidFields=false, ignoreUnknownFields=true, ignoreNestedProperties=false); nested exception is org.springframework.validation.BindException: org.springframework.boot.bind.RelaxedDataBinder$RelaxedBeanPropertyBindingResult: 2 errors
Field error in object 'company.services.verification' on field 'redirectUrl': rejected value [null]; codes [NotNull.company.services.verification.redirectUrl,NotNull.redirectUrl,NotNull.java.lang.String,NotNull]; arguments [org.springframework.context.support.DefaultMessageSourceResolvable: codes [company.services.verification.redirectUrl,redirectUrl]; arguments []; default message [redirectUrl]]; default message [may not be null]
Field error in object 'company.services.verification' on field 'countries': rejected value [null]; codes [NotNull.company.services.verification.countries,NotNull.countries,NotNull.java.util.List,NotNull]; arguments [org.springframework.context.support.DefaultMessageSourceResolvable: codes [company.services.verification.countries,countries]; arguments []; default message [countries]]; default message [may not be null]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor$AutowiredFieldElement.inject(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:588)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.InjectionMetadata.inject(InjectionMetadata.java:88)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.postProcessPropertyValues(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:366)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.populateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1264)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:553)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:483)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:306)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:230)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:302)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:197)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.preInstantiateSingletons(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:761)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:867)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:543)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refresh(SpringApplication.java:693)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refreshContext(SpringApplication.java:360)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:303)
    at org.springframework.boot.test.context.SpringBootContextLoader.loadContext(SpringBootContextLoader.java:120)
    at org.springframework.test.context.cache.DefaultCacheAwareContextLoaderDelegate.loadContextInternal(DefaultCacheAwareContextLoaderDelegate.java:98)
    at org.springframework.test.context.cache.DefaultCacheAwareContextLoaderDelegate.loadContext(DefaultCacheAwareContextLoaderDelegate.java:116)
    ... 24 more
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'applicationConfig': Could not bind properties to ApplicationConfig (prefix=company.services.verification, ignoreInvalidFields=false, ignoreUnknownFields=true, ignoreNestedProperties=false); nested exception is org.springframework.validation.BindException: org.springframework.boot.bind.RelaxedDataBinder$RelaxedBeanPropertyBindingResult: 2 errors
Field error in object 'company.services.verification' on field 'redirectUrl': rejected value [null]; codes [NotNull.company.services.verification.redirectUrl,NotNull.redirectUrl,NotNull.java.lang.String,NotNull]; arguments [org.springframework.context.support.DefaultMessageSourceResolvable: codes [company.services.verification.redirectUrl,redirectUrl]; arguments []; default message [redirectUrl]]; default message [may not be null]
Field error in object 'company.services.verification' on field 'countries': rejected value [null]; codes [NotNull.company.services.verification.countries,NotNull.countries,NotNull.java.util.List,NotNull]; arguments [org.springframework.context.support.DefaultMessageSourceResolvable: codes [company.services.verification.countries,countries]; arguments []; default message [countries]]; default message [may not be null]
    at org.springframework.boot.context.properties.ConfigurationPropertiesBindingPostProcessor.postProcessBeforeInitialization(ConfigurationPropertiesBindingPostProcessor.java:334)
    at org.springframework.boot.context.properties.ConfigurationPropertiesBindingPostProcessor.postProcessBeforeInitialization(ConfigurationPropertiesBindingPostProcessor.java:291)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.applyBeanPostProcessorsBeforeInitialization(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:409)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1620)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:555)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:483)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:306)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:230)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:302)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:202)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.config.DependencyDescriptor.resolveCandidate(DependencyDescriptor.java:208)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.doResolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1138)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.resolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1066)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor$AutowiredFieldElement.inject(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:585)
    ... 42 more
Caused by: org.springframework.validation.BindException: org.springframework.boot.bind.RelaxedDataBinder$RelaxedBeanPropertyBindingResult: 2 errors
Field error in object 'company.services.verification' on field 'redirectUrl': rejected value [null]; codes [NotNull.company.services.verification.redirectUrl,NotNull.redirectUrl,NotNull.java.lang.String,NotNull]; arguments [org.springframework.context.support.DefaultMessageSourceResolvable: codes [company.services.verification.redirectUrl,redirectUrl]; arguments []; default message [redirectUrl]]; default message [may not be null]
Field error in object 'company.services.verification' on field 'countries': rejected value [null]; codes [NotNull.company.services.verification.countries,NotNull.countries,NotNull.java.util.List,NotNull]; arguments [org.springframework.context.support.DefaultMessageSourceResolvable: codes [company.services.verification.countries,countries]; arguments []; default message [countries]]; default message [may not be null]
    at org.springframework.boot.bind.PropertiesConfigurationFactory.checkForBindingErrors(PropertiesConfigurationFactory.java:359)
    at org.springframework.boot.bind.PropertiesConfigurationFactory.doBindPropertiesToTarget(PropertiesConfigurationFactory.java:276)
    at org.springframework.boot.bind.PropertiesConfigurationFactory.bindPropertiesToTarget(PropertiesConfigurationFactory.java:240)
    at org.springframework.boot.context.properties.ConfigurationPropertiesBindingPostProcessor.postProcessBeforeInitialization(ConfigurationPropertiesBindingPostProcessor.java:329)
    ... 55 more
```

this is my ApplicationTest class -

```
 @RunWith(SpringRunner.class)
    @SpringBootTest
    public class ApplicationTests {

    @Test
    public void contextLoads() {
    }

}
```

Here is my ApplicationConfig class -

```
@Data
@Configuration
@EnableAutoConfiguration
@ConfigurationProperties(prefix = "company.services.verification")
public class ApplicationConfig {

@NotNull
String smstype;

@NotNull
String fromEmail;

@NotNull
String subjectEmail;

@NotNull
String subjectManual;

@NotNull
List<Integer> countries;

@NotNull
String redirectUrl;
}
```

And my application.yaml file where the abover properties are defined -

```
company:
    services:
      verification:
        smstype: Claims
        fromEmail: noreply@company.com
        subjectEmail: Email Verification
        subjectManual: Claim Initiated
        redirectUrl: http://www.google.com
        countries:
         - 1
         - 2
         - 3
         - 4
```

I went through a lot of answers but the error remains the same.
I am using spring-boot 1.5.6. Any help please?

Comment: Show your config class for unit testing

Comment: update the question with complete error stack, so that we can check the root cause.

Comment: updated. @TahirHussainMir please have a look

Comment: Please also provide ApplicationConfig, the error comes from that bean creation.

Comment: Added @DanielC. Please have a look

Comment: Good here we are!  the ApplicationConfig could't be created because the fields countries and redirectUrl are getting null values, you have many options, one is remove the NotNull annotation from your properties, and try to run your test, if that success then go to ApplicationConfig and make sure that your properties have values assigned and put your NotNull again

Comment: Make sure that company.services.verification values are in your properties file also, it will depend how you need to handle your configuration, another approach is to set default values for  your ApplicationConfig just in case  that the properties are not defined in properties file

Comment: Thanks DanielC. yeah the issue was that @notnull property. But I have defined those properties like others in my application.yaml file..I have added in my question above . Please have a look. why then countries and callbackUrl not getting assigned  and others get assigned?

Comment: Could you please update your codes with imported libraries?

Answer (score 2):

First of all, please add the following dependency to you project and follow the Spring Doc instructions for "**Generating your own meta-data using the annotation processor**"

[http://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/1.5.6.RELEASE/reference/html/configuration-metadata.html#configuration-metadata-annotation-processor](http://Generating%20your%20own%20meta-data%20using%20the%20annotation%20processor)

Here is the maven dependency for generating custom spring meta-data configuration properties

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-configuration-processor</artifactId>
    <optional>true</optional>
</dependency>
```

Your applicationconfig class should also have getters and setters

```
@Configuration
@EnableAutoConfiguration
@ConfigurationProperties(prefix = "company.services.verification")
public class ApplicationConfig {

    @NotNull
    String smstype;

    @NotNull
    String fromEmail;

    @NotNull
    String subjectEmail;

    @NotNull
    String subjectManual;

    @NotNull
    List<Integer> countries;

    @NotNull
    String redirectUrl;

    public String getSmstype() {
        return smstype;
    }

    public void setSmstype(String smstype) {
        this.smstype = smstype;
    }

    public String getFromEmail() {
        return fromEmail;
    }

    public void setFromEmail(String fromEmail) {
        this.fromEmail = fromEmail;
    }

    public String getSubjectEmail() {
        return subjectEmail;
    }

    public void setSubjectEmail(String subjectEmail) {
        this.subjectEmail = subjectEmail;
    }

    public String getSubjectManual() {
        return subjectManual;
    }

    public void setSubjectManual(String subjectManual) {
        this.subjectManual = subjectManual;
    }

    public List<Integer> getCountries() {
        return countries;
    }

    public void setCountries(List<Integer> countries) {
        this.countries = countries;
    }

    public String getRedirectUrl() {
        return redirectUrl;
    }

    public void setRedirectUrl(String redirectUrl) {
        this.redirectUrl = redirectUrl;
    }
}
```

**EmailController.class**

```
@Controller
@Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
@RequestMapping(value = "/verify/email")
public class EmailController {

    @Autowired
    private ApplicationConfig config;

    @ResponseBody
    @RequestMapping(method = RequestMethod.POST, produces = MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
    public String newRequest(@RequestBody String email) throws
            IOException {

        return email;
    }
}
```

Since i dont have any idea about your byEmail class in your controller i removed it.

**Application.yaml**

```
company:
  services:
    verification:
      from-email: noreply@company.com
      redirect-url: http://www.google.com
      subject-email: Email Verification
      smstype: Claims
      subject-manual: Claim Initiated
      countries:
        - 1
        - 2
        - 3
        - 4
```

And here is the most important part, you should add applicationcontext to your test classes also and make necessary mocking operations before any test.

EmailControllerTests.java

```
@RunWith(SpringRunner.class)
@AutoConfigureMockMvc
@WebAppConfiguration
@SpringBootTest
public class EmailControllerTests {
    @Autowired
    private MockMvc mockMvc;

    @Autowired
    private WebApplicationContext applicationContext;

    @Mock
    private ApplicationConfig applicationConfig;

    @Before
    public void init() throws Exception {
        MockitoAnnotations.initMocks(this);

        // @formatter:off
        this.mockMvc = webAppContextSetup(this.applicationContext)
                .alwaysDo(print())
                .build();
        // @formatter:on

        EmailController emailController = this.applicationContext.getBean(EmailController.class);

        // REPLACE YOUR SERVICES WITH the MOCKED ONES HERE
        //ReflectionTestUtils.setField(emailController, "byEmail", this.byEmail);
        ReflectionTestUtils.setField(emailController, "config", this.applicationConfig);
    }

    @Test
    public void unauthenticatedUsersCannotAddProperty() throws Exception {
        // @formatter:off
        MvcResult result = this.mockMvc.perform(post("/verify/email").contentType(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON).content("{ahmet@ahmet.com}"))
                .andDo(print())
            .andExpect(status().isOk())
            .andReturn();
        // @formatter:on

        Assert.assertNotNull(result);
    }
}
```

And here is the result, everything is working as it should be...

[image]

Hope this helps...

Comment: Why do we need to have getters and setters in ApplicationConfig. Without these it works fine. And when we have @AutoConfigureMockMvc then I guess we dont have to do any kind of pre initialization I guess.

Comment: See this link . I followed this link - [link](https://spring.io/guides/gs/testing-web/)

Answer (score 0):

Try with this application.yaml, just one tab for all properties after verification section.

```
company:
    services:
      verification:
        smstype: Claims
        fromEmail: noreply@company.com
        subjectEmail: Email Verification
        subjectManual: Claim Initiated
        redirectUrl: http://www.google.com
        countries:
          - 1
          - 2
          - 3
          - 4
```

Option2: instead of .yaml use `application.propterties` create the `application.propterties` file in the `resources` folder and the content should be like this:

```
company.services.verification.smstype: Claims
company.services.verification.fromEmail: noreply@company.com
company.services.verification.subjectEmail: Email Verification
company.services.verification.subjectManual: Claim Initiated
company.services.verification.redirectUrl: http://www.google.com
company.services.verification.countries[0]: 1
company.services.verification.countries[1]: 2
company.services.verification.countries[2]: 3
company.services.verification.countries[3]: 4
```

Example of a Config Class

```
@Configuration
@ConfigurationProperties(prefix = "company.services.verification")
public class MyConfig {


    private String smstype;


    private String fromEmail;


    private String subjectEmail;


    private String subjectManual;


    private List<Integer> countries;


    private String redirectUrl;

    public String getSmstype() {
        return smstype;
    }

    public void setSmstype(String smstype) {
        this.smstype = smstype;
    }

    public String getFromEmail() {
        return fromEmail;
    }

    public void setFromEmail(String fromEmail) {
        this.fromEmail = fromEmail;
    }

    public String getSubjectEmail() {
        return subjectEmail;
    }

    public void setSubjectEmail(String subjectEmail) {
        this.subjectEmail = subjectEmail;
    }

    public String getSubjectManual() {
        return subjectManual;
    }

    public void setSubjectManual(String subjectManual) {
        this.subjectManual = subjectManual;
    }

    public List<Integer> getCountries() {
        return countries;
    }

    public void setCountries(List<Integer> countries) {
        this.countries = countries;
    }

    public String getRedirectUrl() {
        return redirectUrl;
    }

    public void setRedirectUrl(String redirectUrl) {
        this.redirectUrl = redirectUrl;
    }
}
```

Comment: Yeah it is at one tab for all properties after verification. By mistake I copied wrong. But still redirectUrl and countries not getting assigned and same null error. :(

Comment: Add setters and getters for each property in your ApplicationConfig class.  setFormEmail(String fromEmail) ; getFromEmail(){ return fromEmail;}, make that for each property.

Comment: added Daniel C. But no affect. Same error Its working fine if I remove @NotNull .. But with it same error:(

Comment: It should be working now, also not sure what  make `@Data` annotation on ApplicationConfig, have you try just let `@Configuration` and `@ConfigurationProperties(prefix = "company.services.verification")`

Comment: @Abhishek I added another alternative using `application.properries`